# How to hide url?

Tags: apache

I want hide URL through redirect rules in .htaccess file.
Suppose my URL is 192.168.1.2/abc/xyz/index.html

I want show only 192.168.1.2/abc

Answer (score 0):

```
# if you have mod rewrite installed in your hosting space, you can enable pretty url for
# compressed css/js by uncommenting following lines

#RewriteEngine On
#Options FollowSymLinks
#RewriteRule   ^packs/(\w+)\.(css|js)   packs/jscsscomp.php?q=$1.$2 

Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

#AuthUserFile /var/www/example.com/public_html/.htpasswd
#AuthType Basic
#AuthName "Login Details Required" 
#require user yourname

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```